# How to use "??=" syntax in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
let a;
a ??= 'asd'
console.log(a); // asd
```

When I run the above js in the browser console without any problems

However, when I run in typescript, an error occurs

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

This is my configuration:

```
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
```

```
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
```

I want to use "??=", need to configure webpack or tsconfig, thanks

Comment: Are you sure your TS installation is up-to-date? Maybe reinstall your node_modules?

Comment: Not sure how did you run your code?

Comment: Also what are you using to compile your TS? If you're using webpack, it may be you're using Babel for the compilation. Not sure what the latest Babel supports, but you may need to check that too.

Comment: The problem isn't with TS 4.1.3; I [can't reproduce your problem](https://tsplay.dev/GmZ7EW)... so it has to do with your particular environment.

Comment: I use webpack and ts-loader @MichaelBauer

Comment: How did you configure your webpack? Did you check your built files then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using both "babel-loader" and "ts-loader", the "??=" syntax can be used normally

```js
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/env"],
          },
        },
        {
          loader: "ts-loader",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
```